# 404 GET error message MathJax

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

```
404 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&delayStartupUntil=configured
```

I can't open a notebook because I continually receive this error message. I just installed Fedora in my laptop, installing things from scratch and have been failing with jupyter notebook installation, my main resource for work.  I tried looking it up, spent hours trying to find a solution (reinstalled jupyter, made a virtual machine,tried a different browser, edited the jupyter-notebook-config.py file) and nothing seems to work.  I have zero clue on how to interpret this error message. Can someone please help???

Answer (score 0):

`sudo dnf install mathjax` fixed the issue for me in Fedora 28 rpm package install (there are guides on how to do it at https://fedoralovespython.org/). They should have made mathjax a dependency in `sudo dnf install python3-notebook`.